# Test vectors for CRC32C

Tags: crc32

I'm writing test harness for an CRC calculation library and I'm looking for reference test vectors for CRC-32C. I found plenty for CRC-32 but nothing for CRC-32C specifically. Could somebody point me to a reference?

I managed to calculate these values using online calculator from [this url](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html):

```
crc32c("") = 0
crc32c("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") = 0x22620404
```

However, I'm not even sure if my setup is correct. All I need is a reference to a reliable source that would provide few test vectors like this.

Comment: The x86 CRC32 instruction uses CRC32C.  You could create simple program to generate your own references if needed.  You still need a pre-baked reference like Mark's answer to reference check your reference checker.

Comment: Here's an online checker: http://checksumcalc.live.conceptcontrols.com/ The CRC32C value you need is at little-endian, reversed 0x82F63B78 in the table.

Comment: @Tobu Very nice, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [CRC catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat.crc-32c) provides the check value of `0xe3069283` for a CRC-32C of the sequence of ASCII characters: "`123456789`" (without the quotes).

Comment: I came across this page myself but I couldn't figure out what the test sequence is :-) Thanks for clearing this out.

Comment: ...and yes the value in the original question checks :-)

Comment: The explanation of the legend params i.e. `check` is here: https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/legend.htm#crc.legend.params

Comment: FYI: checksums from this catalog are in big-endian (network) order.

Comment: @Raman Well, really they're just numbers written in standard notation. Not in big or little endian. I suppose can imagine the hex digits separated into pairs, if you like. But they aren't separated into pairs. There are no bytes -- just integers in hexadecimal.

Comment: @MarkAdler sure, but working backward... to get the correct the CRC-32C checksum integer of `123456789` one must interpret the 4 bytes of `0xe3069283` in big-endian order. For comparison, here is the code Guava uses to convert the checksum to bytes: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/7fd0ff50fbaf0221d9483b99db56ad604ef878d1/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.java#L132-L135 -- as you can see, this is little endian so Guava's hex checksum on the ASCII bytes of `123456789` is "reversed": `0x839206e3`.

Comment: To clarify, your point that `0xe3069283` is simply an integer checksum in base 16 is taken. However, I think my comment is still valid, because `0xe3069283` can just as easily be interpreted as a sequence of 4 bytes in memory, in which case knowing the byte order becomes important.

Answer (score 6):

Here are test data from RFC3720, which uses crc32c.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3720#appendix-B.4

Comment: FYI: the checksums in this document are in little-endian order.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "mee too" answer with some values you can use without parsing standards. The were cross checked with Adler's [`MAKECRC.C`](ftp://ftp.oreilly.co.jp/apache/files/UTILITIES/GZIP/SAMPLE/MAKECRC.C) and Intel's CRC intrinsics.

Adler's implementation was modified to use the the 0x82F63B78 polynomial, which has the following coefficients:

```
/* terms of polynomial defining this crc (except x^32): */
static int p[] = {0,6,8,9,10,11,13,14,18,19,20,22,23,25,26,27,28};
```

Below are String/CRC-32C pairs. Pay attention to endianess. The answers below were extracted byte-by-byte on a little-endian machine, just like a conventional digest would be presented.

```
{"", "\x00\x00\x00\x00"}
{"a", "\x30\x43\xd0\xc1"}
{"abc", "\xb7\x3f\x4b\x36"}
{"message digest", "\xd0\x79\xbd\x02"}
{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "\x25\xef\xe6\x9e"}
{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", "\x7d\xd5\x45\xa2"}
{"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890", "\x81\x67\x7a\x47"}
{"123456789", "\x83\x92\x06\xe3"}
```

Answer (score -1):

To anyone coming here from skimming Google:

Please note that these tests are for `CRC32C`, **NOT** `CRC32`.

`CRC32C` uses a different polynomial and your tests will fail. I had to learn this the hard way.

Comment: This is redundant.  The Question and all of the existing Answers make it clear that they are talking about CRC32C not CRC32.  If people who get here via Google search are not going to read the Question and the other higher voted Answers, what makes you think that they will notice this one at the bottom of the list?   (Everyone has to learn the hard way ... that you need to reading things carefully.  Few people do :-) )